# Bash remote autocompletion : change the 'starting' directory

Tags: bash, rsync, autocomplete

I'm regularly downloading files from a remote server, always from the same directory. So I wrote a custom function that I put in my `bashrc`:

```
download_from_myserver () {
    for file in "$@"
    do
        rsync myserver:/home/pierre/downloads/"$file" .
    done
}
```

Right now, the autocompletion works by default with files in the current directory. I would like to change the autocompletion so that bash automatically connects to the server via `ssh` and autocompletes with files that are in `myserver:/home/pierre/downloads/`.

In case I'm not being clear, here's an example: let's say I have `my_file.txt` in the remote directory, I want to be able to do this:

`download_from_my_server my_fi`<kbd>TAB</kbd>
`download_from_my_server my_file.txt`

How would I do this ?

Notes : I'm already using a password-less connection, rsync and scp autocomplete work well, that's not the issue. I'm using Ubuntu on both machines if that's important.

Comment: Nit: `in "$@"` is redundant in this case - `for` by default loops over the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit*: Sliced it up some more.

You might find this useful, from Debian Administration: [An introduction to bash completion](https://web.archive.org/web/20070312015515/http://www.debian-administration.org:80/articles/316).

---

Complete script: `/some/location/my_ssh_autocomplete_script` (only meant as a short starter):

```
#!/bin/bash

_get_rsync_file_list()
{
    # For test:
    #local -a flist=("foo" "bar")
    #printf "%s " "${flist[@]}"
    # Or:
    ls /tmp
    
    # For live something in direction of:
    #ssh user@host 'ls /path/to/dir' <-- but not ls for other then dirty testing.
}

_GetOptSSH()
{
    local cur

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    case "$cur" in
    -*)
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '-h --help' -- "$cur" ) );;
    *)
        # This could be done nicer I guess:
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$(_get_rsync_file_list)" -- "$cur" ) );;
    esac

    return 0
}
```

Download script `/some/location/my_ssh_download_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

server="myserver"
path="/home/pierre/downloads"

download_from_myserver() {
    for file; do
        rsync "$server:$path/$file"
    done
}

case "$1" in
    "-h"|"--help")
        echo "Download files from '$server', path: '$path'" >&2
        exit 0;;
esac

download_from_myserver "$@"
```

In `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias download_from_myserver='/some/location/my_ssh_download_script'
```

In `.bash_completion`:

```
# Source complete script:
if . "/some/location/my_ssh_autocomplete_script" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Add complete function to download alias:
    complete -F _GetOptSSH download_from_myserver
fi
```

- [COMP_CWORD](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fCWORD)
- [COMP_WORDS](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMP_005fWORDS)
- [COMPREPLY](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-COMPREPLY)

Comment: "Double quote" _every_ expansion, and anything that could contain a special character, eg. "$var", "$@", "${array[@]}", 
                "$(command)". Use 'single quotes' to make something literal, eg. 'Costs $5 USD'. See <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes>, 
                <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments> and <http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words>.

Comment: ls is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in 
                scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are 
                fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention 
                avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works really well! I did use find instead of ls, as pointed out by Rany Albeg Wein but that's the only thing I changed. And thank you for the link to debian-administration.org, I already read it but I wasn't handy enough to make good use of it :p