# Custom help / man -like command (for reminders)

Tags: linux, command-line

I often end up in a situation, where I don't use a command for a while, but then suddenly need to use it; and I need to wade through several help pages until constructing the command line I want. Case in point: occasionally I need to use `nmcli`; and then I need to re-check `nmcli nm help` and `nmcli con help` several times, until I remember what sort of a command I need.

What I have done then, is basically document some of this in a text file; the problem is then I usually save it on Desktop; then every once in a while I clean the Desktop files, so I end up thinking "ah, I don't really use `nmcli-examples.txt` all that much, let me move this one elsewhere too"; then when I need it again, I have to issue a find for it first (provided I can remember the file name to look for).

So I was thinking - making a script that: would have a default location set (e.g. `~/customhelp`), where one could keep specifically these kind of reminder text files; and would list the files in that directory upon `bash` smart completion for the first command argument; and would open such a file name supplied on the command line either in `less` (or in the default GUI text editor if a command line switch is supplied) shouldn't be too difficult.

But I'd rather not try reinventing the wheel, so I was wondering - if any sort of a command for a scheme of usage as described, exists already in a typical GNU/Linux system?

Comment: Why don't you just write a manual page for yourself, containing just the stuff you've put into your text file?

Comment: Setting your bash history to be really, really big would be a start, I think. That's where I go to look for commands I've used before and forgotten about.

Comment: Thanks @SamiLaine - was thinking about that; I am afraid of conflicting names of my text files vs. actual `man` pages; and then also, wanted to avoid thinking about which `man` section should these files belong to. But I guess this is as much of a built-in facility as it goes (also related: [Where are man pages stored in Ubuntu? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/318555/where-are-man-pages-stored-in-ubuntu)); cheers!

Comment: Thanks @FaheemMitha - this, with me needing a specific `nmcli` usage, occurred like a year or more after the last event where I needed the same; I cannot imaging how big should I set the history file, so as to handle needs like this - and even if it was set to that, it would be still tedious to look up something you may have typed a year ago. But it could be an alternative for more frequent events; cheers!

Comment: In addition to having a large history, you can 'tag' commands with key words using '#' at the end of the command. eg. `myvery very long command #joeuser`. This way, if you want to recall the command you just ctrl-r and look for `joeuser` and the command will come up.

Comment: Not a solution, just a thought. I keep a huge file in my home that I append interesting useful commands to. And I grep it when I need it. Very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the comment by @SamiLaine for using `man` - one reason I didn't like it, was because I expected it to be tedious to set up, and I think this post will show that; but, it seems to work. First, some introduction can be found here:

- [HowTo: Linux / UNIX Create a Manpage - nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-creating-a-manpage/) mentions sections, syntax, etc
- [Creating Custom Man Pages | Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-custom-man-pages) mentions `txt2man` (`sudo apt-get install txt2man`)
- [10.04 - How do I add a directory to MANPATH or INFOPATH? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60765/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-manpath-or-infopath)

First let's create the directory and add it to MANPATH:

```
mkdir ~/myreminderhelp
echo 'MANPATH=$MANPATH:'$(echo ~/myreminderhelp) >> ~/.bashrc
```

Let's test if it is found: close the terminal, open a new terminal; and then:

```
manpath -d 2>&1 | grep myrem
```

Unfortunately, this reports nothing for me; even if `echo $MANPATH` says `:~/myreminderhelp`.

Trying with global `/etc/bash.bashrc` (after deleting the line in local `~/.bashrc`, and restarting terminal again):

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'MANPATH=$MANPATH:'$(echo ~/myreminderhelp)" # check home dir printout
sudo bash -c "echo 'MANPATH=$MANPATH:'$(echo ~/myreminderhelp) >> /etc/bash.bashrc"
```

Restart terminal; still `manpath` does not report this directory. Let's now try this:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'MANDATORY_MANPATH  '$(echo ~/myreminderhelp) >> /etc/manpath.config"
```

Close and reopen terminal again; finally, we get:

```
$ manpath 
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/media/extern/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/man:~/myreminderhelp
```

In fact, after finding this, I erased the line from `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and `manpath` still reports the directory. So, I guess editing `/etc/manpath.config` is all that is needed.

Ok, so let's create an example custom reminder file here:

```
echo "Just a bit of a reminder...

Use nmcli con --help" >> ~/myreminderhelp/nmcli-reminder.txt
```

Then use `txt2man` to get a `man` formatted file, and gzip it:

```
cat ~/myreminderhelp/nmcli-reminder.txt | txt2man > ~/myreminderhelp/nmcli-reminder.1
gzip ~/myreminderhelp/nmcli-reminder.1
```

Restart terminal again, try typing `man nm` and press TAB - autocompletion shows `nmcli-reminder` is not found...

So let's try put our files in a `man` section subfolder; the links above indicate section 7 would be appropriate; so:

```
mkdir ~/myreminderhelp/man7
mv ~/myreminderhelp/nmcli-reminder.* ~/myreminderhelp/man7/
tree ~/myreminderhelp # to check - ok
```

Restart terminal again; try typing `man nm` and press TAB - autocompletion finally works:

```
$ man nmcli # and here press TAB:
nmcli           nmcli-reminder
```

... but now we have this problem:

```
$ man nmcli-reminder 
No manual entry for nmcli-reminder
```

Damn it. Could be that currently, our file is `nmcli-reminder.1.gz` indicating section 1 - let's rename it:

```
mv ~/myreminderhelp/man7/nmcli-reminder.1.gz ~/myreminderhelp/man7/nmcli-reminder.7.gz
man nmcli-reminder
```

... and *finally* the `man` command works!

So for this use case, probably it's best to keep the source `.txt` files directly in `~/myreminderhelp/`, and then generate man pages in the appropriate subfolder - as in:

```
$ tree ~/myreminderhelp/
~/myreminderhelp/
├── man7
│   └── nmcli-reminder.7.gz
└── nmcli-reminder.txt
```

... the appropriate generation commands for this being:

```
cat ~/myreminderhelp/nmcli-reminder.txt | txt2man > ~/myreminderhelp/man7/nmcli-reminder.7
gzip ~/myreminderhelp/man7/nmcli-reminder.7
```

And here is a `~/myreminderhelp/buildreminders.sh` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

for ix in $DIR/*.txt; do
  bx=$(basename $ix)
  isn=${bx%%.txt}
  echo Processing $isn;
  set -x
  # txt2man -t "$isn" -s 7 $ix > $DIR/man7/${isn}.7
  pandoc -f markdown -t man -s -o $DIR/man7/${isn}.7 $ix
  gzip --force $DIR/man7/${isn}.7
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
done

tree -a $DIR
```

---

EDIT: Turns out, it is very difficult to get `txt2man` to leave literal source code unformatted, as it tends to auto-extract information like `man` (sub)sections etc. I've modified the script above to use `pandoc` instead (via [WritingManPages - HerzbubeWiki](http://wiki.herzbube.ch/index.php/WritingManPages)) -- at least with `pandoc` with a Markdown input, you have some control over what is literal preformatted text, and what isn't ...

However, both of these tools will indent contents, as is typical for a `man` page (since there, section headings are non-indented, rest of the text content as in paragraphs, is). And I'm not sure I end up liking that all too much...

Answer (score 1):

Right, here is also a script with autocompletion as described in the OP; you could store it in `~/myreminderhelp/` directory as in the `man` answer, and then symlink it to `/usr/bin`. It should read all `*.txt` files in its directory, and make them available (without the extensions) through autocompletion; spaces in filenames should be handled. So you could call:

```
$ help-remind #[TAB] here:
nmcli-reminder  test reminder   
$ help-remind test\ reminder # `less` starts here
```

... or you could use something like this to open the files in a text editor:

```
scite "$(help-remind --getpath test\ reminder2)"
```

... which will also open non-existing files, so you can start editing them.

Here is the code for `help-remind.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sdaau, mar 2014

# symlink this script as:
# sudo ln -s $(readlink -f help-remind.sh) /usr/bin/help-remind

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/277826
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

# declare here all options:
opts="--dumpopts --getdir --getpath"

function main() {
  [ ! -f /etc/bash_completion.d/help-remind ] &&
    generate_bash_completion ;
  # regex check of arguments - if contain "--getdir":
  [[ "$@" =~ --getdir ]]; REC=$?;
  if [[ $REC == 0 ]] ; then
    getdir
    exit
  fi
  [[ "$@" =~ --dumpopts ]]; REC=$?;
  if [[ $REC == 0 ]] ; then
    echo "$opts"
    exit
  fi
  [[ "$@" =~ --getpath ]]; REC=$?;
  if [[ $REC == 0 ]] ; then
    # expecting name without .txt here as second arg;
    # but handle also if it is given
    tfile="${2%%.txt}.txt"
    trlfile=$(readlink -f "$DIR"/"$tfile") ; #echo ${trlfile}
    # printf quoted too (so spaces are escaped):
    echo $(printf '%q' "$trlfile")
    exit
  fi
  if [[ "$@" == "" ]]; then
    echo "An argument is needed"
    exit
  fi
  # if we got here, we expect the text file name as the first argument
  tfile="${1%%.txt}.txt"
  trlfile=$(readlink -f "$DIR"/"$tfile") ; #echo ${trlfile}
  # open it in `less`
  less "$trlfile"
}

function getdir() {
  echo $DIR
}


function generate_bash_completion() {

# note, this requires terminal restart, each time the file is generated

sudo -s <<-'EOM'
cat > /etc/bash_completion.d/help-remind <<'EOF'

_help-remind()
{
    local cur prev opts
    local hrdir hrfiles hri thrf
    local IFS=$'\n'
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="$(help-remind --dumpopts)"
    # to array:
    IFS=' ' read -a opts <<< "$opts"
    # back to LF separated string:
    opts="$(printf '%s\n' "${opts[@]}")"
    hrdir="$(help-remind --getdir)"
    hrfiles=()
    hri=0
    hrfilestr=""

    # create list of candidate text files; only basenames, no ext
    for file in "${hrdir}"/*.txt; do
      thrf=$(basename "$file")
      thrf="${thrf%%.txt}"
      hrfiles[hri++]="${thrf}"
      hrfilestr=$(printf "%s\n${hrfilestr}" "${thrf}")
    done
    #hrfilestr="$(printf '%s\n' "${hrfiles[@]}")"

    shopt -s extglob

    # just for --getpath, also match candidate text files:
    # compopt -o filenames to get spaces to be escaped once chosen via tab
    case $prev in
      --getpath)
        #_filedir
        compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${hrfilestr}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
        ;;
    esac

    # show options, only if $cur starts with a -
    if [[ ${cur} =~ ^- ]] ; then
      COMPREPLY=( $(echo; compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
      return 0
    # else match candidate text files:
    # compopt -o filenames to get spaces to be escaped once chosen via tab
    elif [[ ${cur} == * ]] ; then
      compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${hrfilestr}" -- ${cur}) )
      return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _help-remind help-remind

EOF
EOM

}

# $@ has to be quoted to handle spaces in filenames
main "$@"



# see also:
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77009/custom-autocomplete-deal-with-spaces-in-filenames
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652492/bash-autocompletion-how-to-pass-this-array-to-compgen-without-significant-whit
# http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/escape-string-in-bash-script-so-it-can-be-used-in-command-line-360664/
```