# How to write a auto-completion bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to run some functions (which I created in `./.bash_func`) in terminal with some files located somewhere. When I type the function and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> I want to list the files located in `./scipts` like `cd ./scipts` <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Please [don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Ubuntu-12.04-LTS-i386

Comment: This should be closed on principle...

Comment: @jasonwryan It was but I have reopened it since it is the only one of the three cross-posts that has an answer. The [AU one](http://askubuntu.com/q/596424/10127) one has been closed and the [SU one](http://superuser.com/questions/889300/) is about to be. Let's keep this one open.

Comment: @terdon It simply rewards selfish behaviour; and it is not as if it is a question that is either unique or of any singular merit.

Comment: @jasonwryan let's discuss it here: [Should we get rid of the "cross-posted" close reason?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3422) and

Answer (score 4):

I did this once:

```
notes () { ... }

complete -F complete_notefiles notes

# following based on 
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77009/custom-autocomplete-deal-with-spaces-in-filenames 
complete_notefiles () {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=()
    pushd ~/Documents/Notes >/dev/null
    _filedir
    popd >/dev/null
}

. ~/.bash_completion_functions
```

I found that I needed to copy 3 functions from /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: `_filedir`, `_tilde`, `_quote_readline_by_ref`

Comment: I couldn't find any folder named `/usr/share/bash-completion/`

Comment: @VinuKevy On Ubuntu 12.04, those functions are in `/etc/bash_completion` .