# Command complete for a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

I want to build a script that permit go fast to a path. I want to know if I can use 'complete' command or other command to autocomplete with the directories under '/var/www/vhosts/'. The script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/$1/httpdocs ]; then
    cd /var/www/vhosts/$1/httpdocs
else
    cd /var/www/vhosts/$1
fi
```

Comment: I fail to see the question, this script looks fine, be sure to **source** it (e.g. using `. myscript.sh ARG` (with a leading dot).

Comment: Yes, it work. I'm using source to interpret it. But not work like I want. The purpose of the script is to save time when accessing the directories. So it would be helpful to autocomplete with directories under the path

Comment: How should it autocomplete when you are telling it to use the first parameter?

Comment: You want to start here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77009/4667